# Android - Refresh ListView back to normal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I have a ListView with these items.

```
<string-array name="ore">
        <item>10:00 - 11:00</item>
        <item>11:00 - 12:00</item>
        <item>12:00 - 13:00</item>
        <item>13:00 - 14:00</item>
        <item>14:00 - 15:00</item>
        <item>15:00 - 16:00</item>
        <item>16:00 - 17:00</item>
        <item>17:00 - 18:00</item>
        <item>18:00 - 19:00</item>
        <item>19:00 - 20:00</item>
        <item>20:00 - 21:00</item>
        <item>21:00 - 22:00</item>
    </string-array>
```

And for example I have a string `12:00 - 13:00`. My method checks if the string is in the list, and then makes the ListView item (containing the string ) not clickable and not enabled.

Now, if i have another string let's say `15:00 - 16:00`, the ListView will have both `12:00 - 13:00` and `15:00 - 16:00` not clickable and not enabled.

The thing is i have a `DatePicker` and everytime I select a new date i want to refresh the listview. So for example today i want to make `12:00 - 13:00` not clickable but if i select tomorrow, i want to make `15:00 - 16:00` not clickable but `12:00 - 13:00` should be clickable.
The question is, is there a method that can help me refresh the listview so i can make every item clickable again?

Note: i have tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `listView.invalidateViews()` and nothing worked

Thank you!

Comment: You have to recreate the adapter with original list from string array.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that also but apparently i did something wrong but it didn't work. It's working now! Thank you!